# Why does a section program not run?

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB and I can’t figure out how to make the section divider work. I can’t make the sections work and I can’t run the program. I know there are errors, there are suppose to be there. But I can’t make it run one specific section, it runs the entire program.

Comment: Could you share some of your code and the error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Sample code

```
x = linspace(0,2);
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y)
%% --- SECTION ---
y = sin(x).*cos(20*x);
plot(x,y)
```

Then i just move cursor to some section and press Ctrl+Enter

Comment: Or command+enter on Mac, or by clicking the "Run Section" button in the toolbar at the top of the window.